# jquery click not chaning text/numbers correctly with if conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm writing a like button with jquery but I have some problems with conditionals.

Other problem that I have is with the total_likes counter: if I click like and click unlike the counter is set to 0 but if I like again te counter goes to 2 instead of 1...

The php/html:

```
if (total_likes > 0) {
    $hide = 'block';
} $hide = 'none';

$photos_box .= '<input type="hidden" class="tl' . $imgID . '" value="' . $total_likes . '" />
<a id="' . $imgID . '" class="like_button" title="' . $like_title . '">' . $like . '</a>

//the counter
<a id="" style="display: '. $hide . '">
    <span id="color" class="mod' . $imgID . '">' . $total_likes . '</span>
</a>
// the text
<li id="counter" style="display: ' . $hide . ';">
    <div id="">
        <span class="text_color">' . $text . '</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

The jquery script:

```
$('.like_button').click(function() {

    var total_likes = $('.tl'+this.id).val();
    total_likes = parseInt(total_likes);

    var status = '';

    if ($(this).html() == 'Like') {
        status = 'like';

        $(this).html('Unlike');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Unlike this');
        $('.mod'+this.id).html(total_likes+1);

        if (total_likes == 0) {
            $('#counter').slideToggle('fast');
            $('.text_color').html('Like this.');
        } else if (total_likes == 1) {
            $('.text_color').html('You and <a id="A_112">other</a> like this.');
        } else if (total_likes > 2) {
            var tl = total_likes+1;
            $('.text_color').html('You and <a id="A_112">'+tl+' others</a> like this.');
        }
    } else if ($(this).html() == 'Unlike') {
        status = 'unlike';

        $(this).html('Like');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Like this');
        $('.mod'+this.id).html(total_likes-1);

        if (total_likes == 0 || total_likes == 1) {
            $('#counter').slideToggle('fast');
        } else if (total_likes == 2) {
            $('.text_color').html('<a id="A_112">1 person</a> like this.');
        } else if (total_likes > 2) {
            var tl = total_likes-1;
            $('.text_color').html('<a id="A_112">'+tl+' people</a> like this.');
        }
    }

    var data = {
        img_id : this.id,
        sta    : status
    };

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '/includes/like.php',
        data : data
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Working with jquery and real time changes is a mess... I'm not sure if the conditionals are correct to do what it needs.

I don't know why is like_counter-1 is doing -2 and like_counter+1 is doing +2...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `if (total_likes > 0) {
    $hide = 'block';
} $hide = 'none';` makes no sense

Comment: Why? If I don' want to show that if there are no likes. It's an empty space with icon and no numbers/text

Comment: Um, according to that code everything will be hidden. unless that is some weird php else syntax that I have not seen.

Comment: Not everything, just the counter and the text, the image and other things that there's no need to include are not hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to print two times $total_likes... Just use your actual counter:

```
var total_likes = $('.mod'+this.id).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking, you may want to use some template engine like Smarty or some other while working as it will lead to messy code soner or later.

The problem you are facing is because you are not assigning the updated value to your hidden field. So ultimately you are replacing the value for once but you are again getting the value from the field which is not updated

```
$('.tl'+this.id).val();
```

So you may like to do something like this

```
total_likes = total_likes+1
$('.mod'+this.id).html(total_likes);
$('.tl'+this.id).val(total_likes);
```

Hope this will be of some help

Happy Learning :)